# IntelliJ persistence tool type mapping

Tags: java, postgresql, intellij-idea, persistence

I have a PostgreSQL database schema. And I am trying to generate JPA entities from that schema in IntelliJ with the integrated persistence tool. Everything works fine, except the mapping of timestamps.

The persistence tool is trying to map the PostgreSQL `TIMESTAMP` data type to `java.lang.Object` or `java.io.Serializable`. I can't change the mapping to `LocalDateTime`, `String` or anything else.

Is there any way to set the correct mapping types?

UPDATE:

I get the following exception:

```
SchemaManagementException: Schema-validation: wrong column type encountered in column [timestamp] in table [ProcessEvent]; found [timestamptz (Types#TIMESTAMP)], but expecting [bytea (Types#VARBINARY)]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you used the proper annotation for the attribute?

```
@Entity
public class Employee {
    ...
    @Basic
    @Temporal(DATE)
    private Calendar startDate;
    ...
}
```

Please see: https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/Basic_Attributes#Temporal.2C_Dates.2C_Times.2C_Timestamps_and_Calendars

Comment: Ok, I had to use Calendar or java.sql.time.